# Distinct List of Year and Month from a List of Objects using C# and MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, list, distinct

I hope you guys can assist me. I am still learning C# and interacting with MongoDB. I have looked at some other posts already, and my I tried to model my code on that.

**I am trying to read and compile a `List` of Distinct Year values and Month values from a `List` of objects that has a `DateTime` property.**

My `Holiday` object looks like this:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Holiday))]
public class Holiday
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Holiday Id")]
    public int HolidayId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Holiday Date Time")]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime HolidayDateTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Holiday Name")]
    public string HolidayName { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code I have thus far. With squiggly lines under the `result = new CommandResult<Holiday>(UniqueMonthYears, "Months and Yearsfound",` CommandStatus.Success); The types are incorrect, and I am hoping that someone would have a suggestion how to return my `List`, and where I have made my other mistakes.

```
public CommandResult<Holiday> ReadYearAndMonth()
{
    CommandResult<Holiday> result = null;
    try
    {
        var collection = this.GetMasterCollection<Holiday>();
        var filter = Builders<Holiday>.Filter.OfType<Holiday>();

        List<Holiday> holidays = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        List<DateTime> UniqueMonthYears = holidays.Select(t => new DateTime(t.HolidayDateTime.Year, t.HolidayDateTime.Month, 1))
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();

        result = new CommandResult<Holiday>(UniqueMonthYears, "Months and Yearsfound", CommandStatus.Success);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = new CommandResult<Holiday>(ex, "Error reading Months and Years");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean that the types are incorrect?

Comment: Isn't GetResult() will give You the CommandResult<Holiday>? I think You don't have to generate CommandResult. MongoDB will communicate with You through CommandResult

Comment: looking at the API, the ComandResult object constructor only accepts two inputs, an IMongoCommand and a BSON document http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.3/html/81608f4f-d3cf-68ba-203a-8eb065dbc021.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's assistance - it is greatly appreciated!

I figured out my mistakes and how to fix the method to return the correct results.

I hope this will help someone else struggling with similar issues.

Here are 2 possible solutions (I went with the first):

**Solution 1:** Using BsonDocuments to build a MongoDB Aggregate, Group and Project query, changing the type to `<int>`

```
public CommandResult<int> ReadYearAndMonth()
{
    CommandResult<int> result = null;
    try
    {
        var collection = this.GetCollection<Holiday>();
        var group = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "year", new BsonDocument("$year", "$HolidayDateTime") }
                }
            }
        };

        var project = new BsonDocument
        {
            {"_id", 0},
            {"HolidayDateTime", "$_id.year"}
        };

        var years = collection.Aggregate().Group(group).Project(project).ToListAsync().Result;

        List<int> uniqueMonthYears = years.Select(x => x["HolidayDateTime"].AsInt32).ToList();

        result = new CommandResult<int>(uniqueMonthYears, "Years found", CommandStatus.Success);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = new CommandResult<int>(ex, "Error reading Years");
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Solution 2:** Using LINQ and changing the type to `<int>`

```
public CommandResult<int> ReadYearAndMonth()
{
    CommandResult<int> result = null;
    try
    {
        var collection = this.GetCollection<Holiday>();

        List<Holiday> holidays = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        List<int> UniqueYears = holidays.Select(t => t.HolidayDateTime.Year)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();

        result = new CommandResult<int>(uniqueYears, "Years found", CommandStatus.Success);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = new CommandResult<int>(ex, "Error reading Years");
    }
    return result;
}
```